# SerializationException in atmosphere using @MangedService

Tags: java, serialization, gwt, atmosphere

Im getting an error when trying to use the Atmosphere framework together with GWT 2.8.

Im following the tutorial created by the developer but I'm getting the following error when ever I try to send  a message to server.

Exception: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'toString_0_g$' of null ConsoleLogger.java:55
2016-10-11 14:08:11.699TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString_0_g$' of null
    at y5M_g$ [as onMessage_0_g$] (os2-0.js:94191:85)
    at stL_g$ [as onMessage_0_g$] (os2-0.js:639645:32)
    at Object. (os2-0.js:639422:20)
    at ZM_g$ (os2-0.js:13939:28)
    at aN_g$ (os2-0.js:13995:16)
    at Object.onMessage (os2-0.js:13975:14)
    at _f (127.0.0.1:9264/os2/atmosphere.js:2766:31)
    at _invokeFunction (127.0.0.1:9264/os2/atmosphere.js:2755:17)
    at _invokeCallback (127.0.0.1:9264/os2/atmosphere.js:2885:21)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange (http://127.0.0.1:9264/os2/atmosphere.js:2109:33)

I will greatly appreciate any insight as to what might be causing this error. thanks

Comment: Based on my experience I doubt  atmpshere gwt 2.4.x yet supports any version of GWT 2.8. The perfect working pair for me is GWT 2.7 with atmosphere 2.4.0

Comment: Supervisor is bent on having the latest even if the old one is working just fine, but thanks for the answer!  @Ajax